# Access 2003 objects are hidden behing UI

Tags: ms-access

A client has given me an Access 2003 database that I need to export the data from.
The problem is the database has some kind of  a UI built above it - which essentially locks access to the data tables etc - even the main navigation menu is different.

Any idea how I can strip the UI off the database itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We had our system set up this way to restrict access to the tables, queries.

Hold the SHIFT key down when opening the database.

Comment: Thanks - When i presses on SHIFT while the security warning came - that worked!